# PDB file from different versions of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windbg, pdb-files, postmortem-debugging

I have an old DLL file which was built with VC++ 6. Now I need to investigate the dump file but I don't have its PDB available. The stacktrace reported by WinDbg is also inaccurate.

Is it possible to rebuild the project with later versions of Visual Studio i.e. 2003, 2005, 2008, have the PDB generated, and use this to map addresses to symbols in the old DLL? Is there something like VC 6.0 compatible mode for building project?

Obtaining VC++ 6 is one option, but it looks like VS6.0 has already vanished from MSDN subscriber download page :(

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not even sure whether two builds with the same compiler generate identical PDBs.

Comment: @MSalters: they don't.  But the IDE can read whatever PDB.

Comment: Not sure if these PDBs from the same compiler differ only in timestamps? since my colleague was able to obtain correct stack trace with PDB file newly created from the same compiler. Thanks for this anyway :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I think the answer is no: you'll need to try and rebuild it with the same tool-chain exactly as the binary that generated the dump file you have.

VS is really fussy about how it matches dump files to pdb files in my experience: the only luck I've ever had in these situations is with WinDbg (but you've tried that)/

Comment: Thanks! I also tried to rebuild my project with VS2003 today and found other compatibility issues (obsoleted headers.) Looks like I have to use get VS6.0 somehow anyway :'(